# Add class members and data members of constructor to a list in c#

Tags: c#

I have class like this:

```
public class X
{
    public X()
    {
        Comments = new List<Y>();

    }

    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string Key;

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public List<Y> Comments;     
}

[DataContract]
public class Y
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string Body;

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Author;
}
```

Here is how I'm adding to list.

```
private List<X> Method(string result)
{
   List<X> ret = new List<X>
   List<X> temp = new List<X>
        { 
             new Y()
            {
                Body = Body,
                Author = Author
            },

            new X() {

            Key = issueKey,

            }  
        };
    ret.Add(temp);
    return ret;
  }
```

Am I doing something wrong?
I'm getting error: Add for collection initializer has some invalid arguments,  Please suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to add a new `Y` to a list of `X`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private List<X> Method(string result)
    {
        List<X> ret = new List<X>();
        X temp = new X
        {
            Comments = new List<Y>
            {
                new Y() { Author = "Author", Body = "Body" }
            },
            Key = "issueKey"
        };

        ret.Add(temp);
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Y` is not an `X` so cannot be added to a `List<X>`